# How to set field during runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, types, runtime, member

I was trying to set property of runtime choosen type but it always ends with MissingFiledException. I have tried to create Instance by InvokeMember method and Activator.CreateInstance(type).
Generally i want to assign fields from type to type the simpliest way, that aren't similar eachother by interface or derived class (e.g Data2 and AssignmentData classes).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Data ww =  GetBase(typeof(Data), new AssignmentData(){Id= 5, Text= "qq"}) as Data;
        Data2 ww2 = GetBase(typeof(Data2), new AssignmentData() { Id = 77, Text = "qrrq" }) as Data2;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Object GetBase(Type type, AssignmentData ass)
    { 
        List<string> membersName = new List<string>(type.GetMembers().ToList().Select(x => x.Name));
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        //    type.InvokeMember(null, 
        //BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
        //BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
        //BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, null);
        //if(membersName.Any(x => x == "Id"))
        //{
        //    type.InvokeMember("Id", 
        //        BindingFlags.Public | 
        //         BindingFlags.SetField, null, obj, new Object[] {ass.Id});
        //}
        if(membersName.Any(x => x == "Text"))
        {
            type.InvokeMember("Text", 
                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetField, null, obj, new Object[] { ass.Text });
        }
        return obj;
    }
    public T GetInstance<T>(Type type) where T : Type
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}

class BaseData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class Data : BaseData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class Data2 : BaseData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class AssignmentData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you looking for in the end result? The value of AssignmentData.Text to end up in the value of Data.Text or Data2.Text?

If that is what you want then set the property directly instead of using InvokeMember.

```
    ....
    ....
    if(membersName.Any(x => x == "Text"))
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = type.GetProperty("Text");
        propInfo.SetValue(obj, ass.Text, null);
    }
    ....
    ....
```

Also, note that you are trying to set a property not a field. Your classes don't have a field called Text, they have a property called Text. If you really want to use InvokeMember then change BindingFlags.SetField to BindingFlags.SetProperty or change Text to a field (just a public variable).

Comment: Thanks a lot man. How can i thank you better way than accept the answer? I mean any badges or some?

Comment: I just wnated to fill Data2 properties by values from DataAssignment. I have replaced `GetMembers()` to `GetPrperties()`

Comment: No problem. I guess just up vote the answer as well.